# how to create glass of transform UIView with horizontal swiping cells in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode11.2.1

[I tried with iCrousel library but not able to do glass form UIView in swift . I want to create horizontal swiping of cells in list with horizontal scrolling in swift .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLUTS.png)

I wan to create UIView with collection views should swipe left right like Carousel in swift .if any can  give idea would be appreciable thanks advance.

Comment: There are lots of library you will get for this. iCrousel is good option. try to use "Rotary" option from it. but you need to customised it.

Comment: @PALAKMobileTeamLeader - ok is there any way without  library ?

Comment: without library it is possible but too lengthy.. so better use library

Comment: @PALAKMobileTeamLeader - ok